# How can I develop an android that control my LEGO NXT via bluetooth?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I have Eclipse installed and I know how to develop android apps, but I didn't find how to communicate with the LEGO NXT.
I heard something about the [LEGO Communication Protocol](http://wiki.tinyclr.com/images/d/df/LEGO_MINDSTORMS_NXT_Direct_commands.pdf), but I didn't find the libraries that give me the direct methods.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [NxtJLib](http://www.aplu.ch/home/apluhomex.jsp?site=27)

Also, there are some [samples](http://www.aplu.ch/home/apluhomex.jsp?site=145) on the site.

[One more example](http://www.smartlab.at/articles/android-wifi-htm5-nxt-robot-controller/) with the working code.

*By the way, this is the first link by the Google Search `"lego nxt android library"`. Please, do some research before asking here.*